# ​NuxtJS - Cannot add a file upload button to each row of an element

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

As the title says.
I use NuxtJS in my project.

You cannot add a file upload button to each line of an element.

The reference codes are as follows:.
What is wrong with the script?

```
<tr v-for="profile in profiles" :key="profile.importProfileId" class="border-b-1 border-gray-200" >
  <td class="py-4">{{ profile.title }}</td>
  <td class="py-4">{{ profile.description }}</td>
  <td class="py-4">{{ profile.type }}</td>
  <td class="py-4">{{ profile.format }}</td>
  <td class="py-4">
    <input
      type="file"
      :ref="profile.importProfileId"
      class="hidden"
      accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
      @change="uploadFile" />
    <button
      type="button"
      class="text-xs text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
      style="background-color: rgb(112, 74, 255)"
      @click="$refs.inputTypeFile[`${profile.importProfileId}`].click()">
      Import
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `You cannot add a file upload button...`? What is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I try the code is working fine, check this out:

```
<div id="root">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="profile in profiles" :key="profile.importProfileId" class="border-b-1 border-gray-200" >
      <td class="py-4">{{ profile.title }}</td>
      <td class="py-4">{{ profile.description }}</td>
      <td class="py-4">{{ profile.type }}</td>
      <td class="py-4">{{ profile.format }}</td>
      <td class="py-4">
        <input
          type="file"
          :ref="profile.importProfileId"
          class="hidden"
          accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
          @change="uploadFile" />
        <button
          type="button"
          class="text-xs text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
          style="background-color: rgb(112, 74, 255)"
          @click="$refs.inputTypeFile[`${profile.importProfileId}`].click()">
          Import
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    profiles: [
      {
        importProfileId: 0,
        title: 'title',
        descroption: 'description',
        type: 'type',
        format: 'format'
      },
      {
        importProfileId: 1,
        title: 'title',
        descroption: 'description',
        type: 'type',
        format: 'format'
      },
      {
        importProfileId: 3,
        title: 'title',
        descroption: 'description',
        type: 'type',
        format: 'format'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    uploadFile() {
      
    }
  }
});
```

The output is like this:

[image: Result]